# Using functions on multi-indexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I think this is a basic question but I have not been able to find a usable solution yet. I have some data that is multi-index by month and year as in this attached figure
[image: dataframe]
I want to do some transformations on some columns for each `year` and `month`. Let's say I have some function:

```py
def foo(series):
   return series/series.max()
```

So I would like to apply this function to some column (say, `vol`) for every month of every year, rather than for all the data at once. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html), because function return `Series`:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby(['year','month'])['vol'].transform(foo)
```

Alternative here is:

```
df['new'] = df['vol'].div(df.groupby(['year','month'])['vol'].transform('max'))
```